# Splitting one big ActiveRecord model into multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I have a model called `Agency` that has a lot of fields:

`name`, `state`, `promotion`, `offers_limit`, `promotion_type` etc.

Plus extra data for agency imprint like `imprint_agency_name`, `imprint_tax_id`, `imprint_city`, `imprint_street`, `imprint_house_number`, `imprint_email`, `imprint_phone` etc.

Plus extra fields for agency office address (agency can have office or can not have office, so this data is not always present).

Is it good idea to move imprint data to separate related model `Imprint`, so that in `Agency` I will have `has_one :imprint` and `Imprint` will have `belongs_to :agency` relations? And what about creating `Office` model (with only 4-6 fields) related to `Agency`?

Comment: I would say that it is a good idea. Both short and long term. If you later need to create a different model that can have an office or an imprint you only have to make the connection polymorphic. It is also easier to test and understand small models

Comment: Yes, really good point

Comment: Also from a database point of view. Mysql (or most table based databases) are better with lean tables and it is easier to fetch only the data you need att the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Albin said, splitting one big model into multiple models turned out to be a good thing, especially when it came to relations, tons of validations, custom validations etc. The simpler - the better. And easier to test.